# iOS how to set custom title for the status bar back button for inter-app switching?

Tags: navigation, ios10, statusbar

Is there a programmatic way to change how the title of the "back" button in the status bar? For example, when I open Safari, the back button says "MyApp".

**Is there a way to change the status bar button to say "Back"?**
Is there  a custom PList option I can set just for this button's appearance?

[image]